# Embedding a new region to a content-type node template

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm new to Drupal, and the Drupal website is currently down, ahh!

I need to know how to add a region to a custom node template. I've tried adding the following function to **template.php** in the **my_theme** directory:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) {
```

$vars['usersummary'] = theme('blocks', 'usersummary');
    }

And then printing $usersummary in my node template **node-content_type.tpl**, but it doesn't work - I suspect because the template I need to show the block in is a node template for a specific content type named **node-content_type.tpl**.  If I change the above function to

```
function my_theme_preprocess_node-content_type(&$vars, $hook) {
```

...
    }

I get an error.  Note that I didn't intially set this site up, thus I need to work with existing theme setup, which I don't think is ideal but I don't really think is ideal, but am on a tight deadline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow it turned out to be really easy. All I had to do was add the following into my **node-content_type.tpl**:

```
<?php print theme('blocks', 'usersummary'); ?>
```

No need for the **template.php** file.